# Is it possible to populate a SQL chart with data that depends on the existence of information from that chart?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm aware that this could be a circular dependency but I'm wondering if there's a way around it. I'm writing a database that compares music charts. What I have is:

- a `song` entity
- a `chartentry` entity that has a `song` as an attribute
- specific versions of the `chartentry`: the `spotifychartentry`, `billboardchartentry`, and `rollingstonechartentry`

I am planning on web scraping the chart data from the Spotify, Billboard, and Rolling Stone websites to populate the tables. The issue I have is: when building the database, the dependency dictates that the song, then chart entry be made in that order.
But when I'm populating data, I want the song information to actually come from the web-scraped data of the charts. So the order of populating data becomes: chart data->song. I do not just have a table of every song in existence.
Is the order of populating this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Each time you receive a new chart entry from your data source (your scraper), first look at your `song` table to determine whether it is present already.

If it isn't, INSERT it into that table.
Then determine its `song_id` value (where `song_id` is the primary key on that table).

Your query to find out whether it's present will need some care; you probably need to do at least some fuzzy-matching to deal with variants of names of songs, acts, versions, etc. If my experience is anything to go on, this will take a while to do perfectly.

Then insert a row into the chartentry table giving the `song_id` of the song mentioned, the date of the chart entry, and the other particulars of the entry ( `place`= 8, `bullet` = 'yes' for example).

Don't create separate tables for each source of chart entries; instead put an attribute (a column) in the table indicating the source.  That way you may be able to handle Billboard's different charts (Country, R&B, Rock, etc) more easily.

Comment: And, be careful... Billboard and Rolling Stone defend their copyrights aggressively.

Comment: "Don't create separate tables for each source of chart entries; instead put an attribute (a column) in the table indicating the source." I decided to create different tables because different music charts have different attributes. For example Spotify has `stream #` whereas Billboard does not. Billboard has `# weeks on chart`, `peak position`, etc. Also I was only intending on taking the 'main' charts from each service so I wasn't intending on handling Billboard's different charts.